# Ignoring some alignments

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, alignat

I'm struggling to display this kind of aligned expression in Latex :

```
         expression1 = expression2
\implies expr1 = expr2
               = simpler_expr2
```

I wanted to put `align` environnement inside another one to do the second alignement, but the interpreter didn't like that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: It would help if you were a bit more specific as to what exactly "the interpreter didn't like that" entails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to interpret you query.

- One could align all three rows on their `=` symbols. This formatting objective may be achieved with the help of a single `aligned` environment.
- One could treat rows 2 and 3 as a sub-block. Then, the first row and the sub-block would be aligned on the first occurrences of the letter `e` in rows 1 and 2, while the rows within the sub-block would be aligned on their respective `=` symbols. Here, one would employ nested `aligned` environments. The second, or "inner", `aligned` environment would employ a `[t]` positioning specifier, to inform LaTeX where to place the `\implies` symbol.

The LaTeX code for both possibilities is given below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for a better-looking underscore character
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' env. and '\text' and '\implies' macros
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
   \text{expression1} &= \text{expression2} \\
\implies \text{expr1} &= \text{expr2} \\
                      &= \text{simpler\_expr2}
\end{aligned}
\]
\bigskip
\[
\begin{aligned}
&\text{expression1} = \text{expression2} \\
\implies &
     \begin{aligned}[t] % <-- note the '[t]' positioning specifier
     \text{expr1} &= \text{expr2} \\
                  &= \text{simpler\_expr2}
     \end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```